# How to bind a property inside a child element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to use two property values to define if an element is enabled or not.
Until now the following line decided to enable / disable an element. `IsEnabled` is decided based on
the binding to `someContext.SomeObject.Count`

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource CheckButtonStyle}" Margin="1"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=someContext[3], ElementName=MyElementName, IsAsync=True}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding Path=someContext.SomeObject.Count, ElementName=MyElementName, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" />
```

I changed the converter to be a IMultiValueConverter and
I changed the XAML to the following:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource CheckButtonStyle}" Margin="1"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=someContext[3], 
              ElementName=MyElementName, IsAsync=True}">
   <ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiValueConverter}" ConverterParameter="3">
         <Binding Path="{someContext.SomeObject.Count}"/>
         <Binding Path="{IsConditionFullfilled}/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
</ToggleButton>
```

However in the first version binding inside curly braces is recognized,
but in the second version I get:

> "The type 'someContext' was not found. Verify that you are not missing
> an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been build."

I think `<ToggleButton.IsEnabled></ToggleButton.IsEnabled>` somehow has no access to the same namespace as its parent `<ToggleButton />`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Remove the curly braces around the name, e.g.: `<Binding Path="someContext.SomeObject.Count"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curly braces around the names, otherwise they will be interpreted as [markup extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

> When used to provide an attribute value, the syntax that distinguishes a markup extension sequence to a XAML processor is the presence of the opening and closing curly braces ({ and }). The type of markup extension is then identified by the string token immediately following the opening curly brace.

Additionally, add the `ElementName` from the original binding if it is still needed.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiValueConverter}" ConverterParameter="3">
   <Binding Path="someContext.SomeObject.Count" ElementName="MyElementName"/>
   <Binding Path="IsConditionFullfilled"/>
</MultiBinding>
```